# Create paid apps in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to publish my app in Play Store with a subscription fees to access some features from the app.

I cannot find the documentation for this. Can anyone guide me how do I know whether the subscription was paid or not, so that I can unlock the features.

Comment: I imagine you should be managing user subscriptions in your backend API, handling subscriptions in the Xamarin app itself doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @Kevin We saw many apps that contains ads and they also provide the paid app with a subscription fee to remove that ad. how they are managing such things.

Comment: Its not something I have done, but I think you will need an API that manages users and their subscription, if in an authorized role (paid subscription) hide adds, if not authorized show adds, if you try manage a subscription in your Xamarin application anytime you make a change to the subscription you rely on the user downloading an update which is not a good idea

Comment: there is a lot of java implementations of this which you should be able to follow even if you do not know Java, generally if you don't know how to implement a line of Java code in Xamarin just google the line of code with in Xamarin and it usually has the answer. a Java solution http://www.tutorialsface.com/2016/05/implementing-remove-ads-in-app-purchases-in-android-tutorial-example/

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/integrating-in-app-purchases-in-mobile-apps/